# VS Code Server: how to configure extensions and settings before connecting?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code to edit files on a remote Linux server.

When I connect, it loads VS Code Server, Node, GitHub Copilot, and god knows how many more extensions. This results in the server returning 509 responses to everybody on it, CPU usage of 33x (i.e. 3300%) and me getting a phone call from the admin.

So BEFORE I connect again I'd like to disable all extensions and have VS Code running as slim as I can get it. How can I configure these things on a per-server basis BEFORE connecting to that server?

Comment: Possible temporary workaround (not sure if this works for remote connections): use the `--disable-extension <ext-id>` flag format. See also the `--list-extensions` flag. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Out of curiosity, would it work for you to just do your development only your local machine and just transfer changes to the remote machine between commits via git?

Comment: I started that approach, but setting up mitmproxy to intercept requests for local development wasn't working. So I have to develop on the server.

Comment: I need to configure this on a per-host (per-workspace?) basis. Because *somebody* (i.e. GitHub Copilot) need to write the code in another window while I connect to that server.

Comment: What about my first comment?

Comment: Doesn't work because I need that extension open at the same time in another window to do work.

Comment: did you actually try it? I'm pretty sure running one window with certain extensions disabled via commandline will not affect other windows.